# SharePoint 2013 rescue attachments

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list

HeyHo, I have the problem that somone has disabled attachements on a list and so all attachments have been deleted. Is there any way to recover this attachments or do I have to restore a snapshot to restore this attachments?

Answer (score 0):

The "content type" has changed, so I presume you can't find it.

Comment: yeah, i have already restored a snapshot and took the attachments from there... thanks anyway